# Launching an application from Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using a bash shell in Mac OS X. I have a 'Eclipse' folder on my Desktop with the launcher icon in it, and I'm trying to open the app like this:

```
cd Desktop
cd Eclipse
Eclipse.app
```

But this gives me an error: `-bash: Eclipse.app: command not found`

Why?

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Crash? Error message? Daemons flying out of your nose?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, i get a command not found: -bash: Eclipse.app: command not found

Comment: OK see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to launch an OS X app.

In OS X only, you use the `open` command for this:

```
cd Desktop/Eclipse
open Eclipse.app
```

`open` is much more versatile than this, and will also open files using the associated program.

To learn more about `open`, type this in the Terminal:

```
man open
```

As already mentioned, `open` is OS X specific.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse .app is a directory. Use this instead:

```
cd Desktop/Eclipse/Eclipse.app
./Eclipse
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mac you should use `open`. It's not only help you open the application but it also open specific file extension with the default application. Like `open <pdf>` will activate preview.

For more information `man open`

Answer (score 0):

To do so, use `open`. Not only you could use `open` on apps, but also other files.
Such as, `open Something.jpg`.